# How to scale labels of the images when resizing the image in css?

Tags: javascript, css, image, debugging, frontend

I have images with labels(bounding boxes), which means they have their own coordinates in a different .txt file. When I show the image with its original size on the web browser, the bounding boxes are shown correctly. Here is my code from java script and css:

```
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var originalWidth = 300;  // original width of .img-box
    var originalHeight = 300;  // original height of .img-box

    $('.image-label').each(function() {
        var label = $(this).data('label');
        var currentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
        var currentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
        
        var scaleFactorWidth = currentWidth / originalWidth;
        var scaleFactorHeight = currentHeight / originalHeight;

        console.log('Scale factors', scaleFactorWidth, scaleFactorHeight);  // logging scale factors

        var x = label[1] * originalWidth;  // calculate the original x coordinate
        var y = label[2] * originalHeight;  // calculate the original y coordinate
        var width = label[3] * originalWidth;  // calculate the original width
        var height = label[4] * originalHeight; // calculate the original height

        console.log('Original dimensions', x, y, width, height);  // logging original dimensions

        var newX = x * scaleFactorWidth;  // scale the x coordinate
        var newY = y * scaleFactorHeight;  // scale the y coordinate
        var newWidth = width * scaleFactorWidth;  // scale the width
        var newHeight = height * scaleFactorHeight;  // scale the height

        console.log('New dimensions', newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);  // logging new dimensions

        $(this).css({
            left: ((newX - newWidth / 2)) + 'px',
            top: ((newY - newHeight / 2)) + 'px',
            width: newWidth + 'px',
            height: newHeight + 'px'
        });
    });
});


      </script>
```

```
.img-box {
    position: relative;  
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}


.img-thumbnail {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}


.img-thumbnail {
    width: 300%;
    height: auto;
}

.image-container {
    position: relative;
}

.image-labels {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.image-label {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

And here is the result:
[before resizing the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC07n.png)

But when I change the css code to resize the image for example:

```
.img-box {
    position: relative;  
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

this is the result:
[The exact error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttBAw.png)

But what I wanted is that I want the labels (bounding boxes) to adjust their size and position proportionally whenever the .img-box size changes.

To achieve this, I had this formula but it didn't help:
Let's assume:

```
H is the original height of the image
W is the original width of the image
H' is the new height of the image
W' is the new width of the image
(x, y) are the original coordinates of the label
(x', y') are the new coordinates of the label
m_h = H'/H is the scale factor for height
m_w = W'/W is the scale factor for width
```

So based on the formulas, we will have:

```
x' = x * m_w
y' = y * m_h
```

Can anyone please help me so the labels adjust their size and position proportionally whenever the .img-box size changes?

To help you more to reproduce the problem here 2 images and their coordinates(must be in a different .txt file):
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQH2E.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKsSU.jpg)

Label coordinates to img 1: 2 0.4675480769230769 0.47596153846153844 0.7283653846153846 0.7752403846153846

Label coordinates to img 2: 6 0.6165865384615384 0.41346153846153844 0.16105769230769232 0.09014423076923077

Comment: You've posted some portions of your code, but not enough for us to easily reproduce the problem. Suggest you edit your question to add a snippet which reproduces the problem. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BrettDonald I have now added all of the codes. I hope it is enough to help you to understand the problem. Besides that I have also added a picture where you see the exact problem.

Comment: **{% for image in images %}** and **{% for label in image.labels %}**. How can we reproduce the problem without the images and the labels? Are these in separate text files? We'll need these too. But as I said, you're more likely to get help if you create a minimal reproducible example as described in the link I included in the previous comment.

Comment: Okay now I also added the images and label coordinates. I have already described that the labels are in text files.